# Asp.Net WebApi handles post request for about 2 minutes

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

When I try to POST(or PUT) my viewModel, represented via JSON

```
PUT /adm/api/places/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:11483
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
  id: 1,
  name: "000000",
  description: "des1",
  published: false
}
```

to my Controller

```
[Route("adm/api/places", Name = "PlacesApi")]
public object PostPlace(PlaceVM place)
{
   // breakpoint hits here only after about 2 minutes
}
```

I have to wait for about 2 minutes before controller's action starts to handle the request.
I figured out that the reason of this is numerous calls to the .net framework function System.Security.Cryptography.CapiHashAlgorithm.HashCore:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize) 
{
    Contract.Assert(m_hashHandle != null);

    if (array == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }
    if (ibStart < 0 || ibStart > array.Length - cbSize) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("ibStart");
    }
    if (cbSize < 0 || cbSize > array.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cbSize");
    }

    byte[] hashData = new byte[cbSize];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, ibStart, hashData, 0, cbSize);

    if (!CapiNative.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptHashData(m_hashHandle, hashData, cbSize, 0)) {
        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```

Parameter 'array' contains byte array of size about 5 MB.

Call stack represented below:

> [Managed to Native Transition]
>
> > System.Core.dll!System.Security.Cryptography.CapiHashAlgorithm.HashCore(byte[]
> >     array, int ibStart, int cbSize) Line 124  C# 
> >       System.Core.dll!System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider.HashCore(byte[]
> >     array, int ibStart, int cbSize) Line 51   C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(byte[]
> >     buffer) Line 85   C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Policy.Hash.GenerateHash(System.Type
> >     hashType, byte[] assemblyBytes) Line 338  C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Policy.Hash.GenerateHash(System.Type
> >     hashType) Line 316    C# 
> >       mscorlib.dll!System.Security.Policy.Hash.SHA256.get() Line 255  C# 
> >       [Lightweight Function]
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForPropertiesImpl.AnonymousMethod__0()  Unknown
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata.Model.get()  Unknown
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateElements(System.Collections.IEnumerable
> >     model,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,
> >     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
> >     validators)   Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext)    Unknown 
> >       System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata
> >     metadata,
> >     System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidationContext
> >     validationContext, object container,

I use webapi 2.2 and VisualStudio 2013 Update 3.
This issue is not reproducing on my production IIS server (v. 8.5), only on development machine with IISExpress.

Request handling pipeline from trace log file please see [here](https://yadi.sk/d/plXsdsOdfGNzA).

**Edit:**
Implementation of the PlaceVM class:

```
 public class PlaceVM : ViewModelBase<Place>
    {
        public PlaceVM()
        {
        }
        public PlaceVM(Place place)
        {
            ID = place.ID;
            Name = place.Name;
            Description = place.Description;
            PlaceTypeID = place.PlaceTypeID;
            Published = place.Published;          
        }
        [EpHiddenField]
        public long? ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [EpTextField(Caption = "Название")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(512, MinimumLength = 30)]
        [EpTextAreaField(Caption = "Описание")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EpLookupField("placeTypes", Caption = "Тип")]        
        public long? PlaceTypeID { get; set; }

        [EpCheckFiled(Caption = "Опубликовано")]
        public bool? Published { get; set; }
    }
```

I finally figured out that the reason of this hanging is EF migrations.
After deleting Migrations folder the problem disappeared.
Automatic migrations are disabled and it is not clear how the presence of Migrations folder causes the problem?

**Edit2**

Base class for ViewModel presented above:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity,  new()
    {
        private class VmAndEntity
        {
            public PropertyInfo ViewModelProp { get; set; }
            public PropertyInfo EntityProp { get; set; }
        }
        private static readonly log4net.ILog _log =
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        protected TEntity _Model;

        protected ViewModelBase(TEntity model, bool fillVmByPropsMap = false)
        {
            if (model == null) // При вызовае JSON.NET сериализатором
            {
                model = new TEntity();
            }
            _Model = model;
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _entityPropsGetters, () => GetEntityPropGetters(this.GetType()));

            if (fillVmByPropsMap)
                FillVMByPropsMap(model);
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] EntityPropsGetters
        {
            get
            {
                if (_entityPropsGetters == null)
                    throw new EpFieldNotInitializedException("_entityPropsGetters");

                return _entityPropsGetters;
            }
        }

        private static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] _entityPropsGetters;
        protected void FillVMByPropsMap(TEntity model)
        {
            if (model == null)
                return;
            if (_vmToEntityPropsMap.Count == 0)
            {
                _log.WarnFormat("_vmToEntityPropsMap is empty for VM '{0}'", this.GetType());
#if DEBUG
                throw new EpInvalidStateException("VM '{0}' has no properties which fit model's properties");
#endif
            }
            foreach (var vmAndEntity in _vmToEntityPropsMap)
            {
                var val = vmAndEntity.EntityProp.GetValue(model, null);
                vmAndEntity.ViewModelProp.SetValue(this, val);
            }
        }

        public abstract TEntity FillModel();
        protected TEntity FillModelByPropsMap()
        {
            if (_vmToEntityPropsMap.Count == 0)
            {
                _log.WarnFormat("_vmToEntityPropsMap is empty for VM '{0}'", this.GetType());
#if DEBUG
                throw new EpInvalidStateException("VM '{0}' has no properties which fit model's properties");
#endif
            }
            if (_Model == null)
                _Model = new TEntity();

            foreach (var vmAndEntity in _vmToEntityPropsMap)
            {
                var val = vmAndEntity.ViewModelProp.GetValue(this);
                vmAndEntity.EntityProp.SetValue(_Model, val);
            }
            return _Model;
        }

        private static List<VmAndEntity> _vmToEntityPropsMap;
        private static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] GetEntityPropGetters(Type vmType) 
        {
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> res = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();
            _vmToEntityPropsMap = new List<VmAndEntity>();

            var vmProperties = vmType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);
            var eProperties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);

            foreach (var vmProp in vmProperties)
            {
                var eProp = eProperties.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == vmProp.Name);
                // Если в модели нашлось свойство, соотвествующее ViewModelProp, то
                if (eProp != null)
                {
                    _vmToEntityPropsMap.Add(new VmAndEntity() { ViewModelProp = vmProp, EntityProp = eProp});

                    // получим Expression для доступа к этому свойству
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
                    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, eProp);
                    Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));
                    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(conversion, parameter);

                    res.Add(lambda);
                }
            }
            return res.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The root of the problem is in the **EntityPropsGetters** property.
Freezing cycle of hash calculation starts after **EntityPropsGetters** property.
And removing this property solves the problem.
It seems that the reason of the problem is in the static method **GetEntityPropGetters**. But I can't understand how all this connected with migrations...

Comment: What are the filters, delegating handlers you have in the web api pipeline

Comment: I've added link to the trace log file. Is it sufficient?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but could you please share the implementation of the `PlaceVM` class. It seems that there is some crazy validation going on there.

Comment: I've added PlaceVM to the question body. But as I said in my Edit, it seems that the reason in migrations. Main question now is why migrations  causes this hanging and how to fix it without deleting migrations.

Comment: I've added new edit.

Comment: @MichaelRatnikov To be honest I haven't used migrations in EF, but from its description it looks that it does some heavy lifting on every application run. Have you tried to log the queries with DbContext.Log? Maybe they will reveal what types of queries are there and why do they take so much time.